# Android sqlite - cursor count not 0 on empty table

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have the following code in a bigger project:

```
final class DBlifetimeStatisticsHandler{ //implements DBvalueHandler<Cyclist, Double>{

private  final String TAG = getClass().getName();
private static final boolean debug = true;

private final DBminMaxAvgHandler dbMinMaxAvgHandler = new DBminMaxAvgHandler();

// table name
private static final String TABLE_LIFETIME_STATISTICS = "lifetime_statistics";

// column names
private static final String KEY_LIFETIME_STATISTICS_ID = "lifetime_statistics_id";
private static final String KEY_MIN_MAX_AVG = "min_max_avg";

// table create statement
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_LIFETIME_STATISTICS + "(" 
        + KEY_LIFETIME_STATISTICS_ID + " LONG PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL," 
        + KEY_MIN_MAX_AVG   + " LONG"
        + ")";

public void onCreateTable(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LIFETIME_STATISTICS);
    onCreateTable(db);
}

public long addValue(SQLiteDatabase db, Statistics Statistics ) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    long ID = getLatestID(db)+1;

    values.put(KEY_STATISTICS_ID, ID);

    ... //not important to the question

}

private long getLatestID(SQLiteDatabase db){
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  MAX(" + KEY_STATISTICS_ID +") FROM " + TABLE_STATISTICS;

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    c.moveToFirst();
    int id = 0;
    Log.e("count", String.valueOf(c.getCount()));

    if (c.moveToFirst()){
       ...
    }

    return id;
}
}
```

After I updated the table it is created again. So when I try to add a new value I had problems cause it always jumped into the if clause because `c.moveToFirst()` always returned true.

So I tried to tried to check if `c.getCount()` would return true but sadly it does always return 1. So the question is: Why would it return 1 on an empty table? (I do use Questoid SQLite Browser and the table is really empty)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use aggregate function `MAX`, so read [documentation:](http://sqlite.org/lang_select.html)

> There are two types of simple SELECT statement - aggregate and non-aggregate queries. A simple SELECT statement is an aggregate query if it contains either a GROUP BY clause or one or more aggregate functions in the result-set.
>
> An aggregate query without a GROUP BY clause always returns exactly one row of data, even if there are zero rows of input data.

Comment: changed it to `String selectQuery = "SELECT  MAX(" + KEY_STATISTICS_ID +") FROM " + TABLE_STATISTICS + " GROUP BY " + KEY_STATISTICS_ID;` and now it works. Is that the correct way or is there a better? Is there a reason for MAX's behavior?

Comment: Better is: `String selectQuery = "SELECT " + KEY_STATISTICS_ID +" FROM " + TABLE_STATISTICS + " ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 1";` - returns one (with max id value) or none records.

Comment: `String selectQuery = "SELECT " + KEY_STATISTICS_ID +" FROM " + TABLE_STATISTICS + " ORDER BY " + KEY_STATISTICS_ID + " DESC LIMIT 1";` would be better I guess, right? But this was a great help, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

It might be some kind of a buggy behavior when using `MAX`. Check this link too [Android database (SQLite) returns a non-empty cursor from an empty table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772876/android-database-sqlite-returns-a-non-empty-cursor-from-an-empty-table)

Answer (score 1):

this is my solution

```
public Boolean isNotEmpty(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_STATISTICS, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext() ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a result with one row in your Cursor because that is what you requested.

The result is a single column called MAX with a value that will be the max id of all the rows in your table.  In your case of an empty table, this value is null.

Comment: I do see the "logic" but I expected the max of nothing being nothing instead of something telling me that it is nothing :D

Comment: Yeah - I understand, but the alternative is that you would be returned a Cursor with no rows which I think would be equally as confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I am using group by to resolve this. Please check my example :

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE isSynced=0 group by isSynced
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this probme this way:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS numero, MAX(tagua_lagps) as tmp_max_lagps, MAX(tagua_logps) as tmp_max_logps, MIN(tagua_lagps) as tmp_min_lagps, MIN(tagua_logps) as tmp_min_logps FROM TAB_AGUA
```

On empty table, *c.getCount();*  gives 1 but values are NULL. But numero (*c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("numero")*) has a value of 0.

So rather than checking *c.getCount()* you must check the result of *count(*)*.